# Connecting RC522 RFID module to Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: python, pi-4, spi, rfid

I connect my RC522 RFID module to my Raspberry Pi 4 according to https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-rfid-rc522/ so we have Write.py and Read.py:

Write.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522

reader = SimpleMFRC522()

try:
        text = input('New data:')
        print("Now place your tag to write")
        reader.write(text)
        print("Written")
finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

and Read.py is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522

reader = SimpleMFRC522()

try:
        id, text = reader.read()
        print(id)
        print(text)
finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

but when i execute `sudo python3 Write.py` this error appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Write.py", line 6, in <module>
    reader = SimpleMFRC522()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mfrc522/SimpleMFRC522.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.READER = MFRC522()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mfrc522/MFRC522.py", line 130, in __init__
    self.spi.open(bus, device)
```

and for Read.py we have almost as same as Write.py execution error something like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Read.py", line 6, in <module>
    reader = SimpleMFRC522()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mfrc522/SimpleMFRC522.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.READER = MFRC522()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mfrc522/MFRC522.py", line 130, in __init__
    self.spi.open(bus, device)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I have tried several ways but did not work at all: 1-checking wiring 2-using python2 3-checking SPI enabling using GUI and also boot/config.txt 4-using `sudo apt-get update` , `sudo apt-get upgrade` , `sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-pip` and `sudo pip3 install spidev`.

I tried `lsmod |grep spi` to check spi and the result was:

```
spidev                 20480  0
spi_bcm2835            24576  0
spi_bcm2835aux         16384  0
```

what is the problem do you think? My Raspberry Pi 4 also had a 3.5-inch touchscreen LCD in the box. Is this the reason that spi0 is reserved? how to fix it? I can't even use another RC522 program those are in github.com and they have almost the same error in spi.open(bus, device).
Is there any way to connect RC522 to my raspberry pi using a USB connection?

Comment: There is no error reported in the first traceback.

Comment: Some troubleshooting suggestions: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/519993/can-rfid-read-stacked-cards/520007#520007

Comment: @joan I think actually one last line is not pasted here maybe. but it's something like the Read.py Traceback. anyway thanks

Comment: @tlfong01 not solved but thanks :)

Comment: Many (WaveShare) LCD display use SPI exclusively and causes trouble. Of course you can put the LCD display away and see if your problem disappears. Another complexity is that PiMyLifeUp's SPI is not the same as Rpi OS's build in SPI, and that might cause confusion.

Comment: You are asking us to guess.  We don't know how the device is connected.  We guess it's via SPI.  We don't know which SPI bus it uses or how it is connected.  We don't know what else is using the SPI bus.  We don't know if SPI is properly enabled.  It's probably too late now as most questions only attract attention for a limited time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the simple answer. just reinstall the Raspbian OS to reset the SPI configuration (which was set for 3.5 inch LCD) so RFID writing and reading work well and everything goes correct.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you have not enabled the SPI interface. You should be able to use raspi-config to do this, but I prefer to modify `/boot/config.txt`. For example, my `config.txt` includes these lines:

```
dtparam=spi=on
# spi0 is used for RFID reader
dtoverlay=spi0-1cs
```

You will need a different overlay if you are not using SPI0.

Comment: Thanks. I edited boot/config.txt to enable SPI0 before but does not work. my config.txt: 'dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtparam=spi=on
enable_uart=1
dtparam=audio=on
dtoverlay=waveshare35a
hdmi_cvt 480 320 60 6 0 0 0
hdmi_drive=2
dtoverlay=spi0-ics
device_tree_param=spi=on
dtoverlay=spi-bcm2708
dtoverlay=spi0-hw-cs' If I wanna use another SPI what should i do? How config.txt should be edited? GPIOs connection and ...?